# Solr - prefix query

Tags: solr

When I search using the query `addr:s*`

I get...(this is dummy data)

```
addr=someword
addr=banana-sunny.or
addr=seventy
addr=salvation
```

I only want those records that start with `s`, but the second record in the result starts with `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are probably using Text analysis for your address field which the split the word into multiple tokens.
In that case the word "banana-sunny" might get split into multiple tokens (banana, sunny, or ).
Hence, the search on s* would return you back the result.
If you don't want the split, define a new field type with KeywordTokenizerFactory and other filters. e.g.

```
<fieldType name="text_string" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Will adding StandardFilterFactory also be useful for other search criteria?

Comment: you can check depending upon search requirements. You can also maintain different copies of fields.